# convert routeParams from string to number

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-toolkit

I have a simple project and in this project I am trying to return data through the id number, and I used “routeParams”, but I had a problem that the “routeParams” is of a string type and I want to convert it to a number, how can I do that?

```
 const routeParams = useParams();
 
  useDeepCompareEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getReceipt(routeParams.orderId));
  }, [dispatch, routeParams.orderId]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it by using Number().

```
const routeParams = useParams();

 useDeepCompareEffect(() => {
   dispatch(getReceipt(Number(routeParams.orderId)));
 }, [dispatch, routeParams.orderId]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the plus sign before the string to make it a number

```
const routeParams = useParams();
 
  useDeepCompareEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getReceipt(+routeParams.orderId));
  }, [dispatch, routeParams.orderId]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) it will return parsed `number` if you have correct value or `NaN` if not