Argument of type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'
Why do I have the error:
Argument of type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
   Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'

'use client'

import { useParams } from 'next/navigation'

export default async function Post() {
    const { id } = useParams()
    const item = await getItem(id)  //<-- here is the error

    return <ul>
        <li><strong>id:</strong>{item.id}</li>
        <li><strong>title:</strong>{item.title}</li>
        <li><strong>body:</strong>{item.body}</li>
    </ul>
  }

  async function getItem(id: string) {
    const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
    return res.json()
  }


As a potential alternative to the proposed duplicate, you could change getItem to accept a string instead of a number, since it just uses the value as a string anyway.  (Or just remove that type annotation entirely, since that's the only place in this component that even uses TypeScript at all and it's not accomplishing anything for you.)

The error message seems pretty clear - id could either be string or string[], and getItem only accepts the former.

Alternate potential duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71293133/convert-routeparams-from-string-to-number, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69993011/how-to-specify-the-result-type-of-useparams-with-react-router-v6

I have changed type of id from number to string and now I have a different error (I edited my post)

Your question is still answered by that error message, though.

Basically... If you want to use TypeScript, use it completely.  (e.g. Add type annotations to the useParams usage, variable declarations, etc.)  If you don't want to use TypeScript, remove it completely.  (e.g. Remove the type annotation from getItem.)
